# Expose HTML fragments as REST API vs Web Components?

Tags: java, rest, content-management-system, web-component

I have a use case where the common sections of the website, "article detail" or "header" needs to be reused across other streams & the teams of my organization as well as some external agencies as well.

We can expose the Content in the form of JSON using REST endpoints but the problem here is that each team will then need to design the UI & we may lose the consistency & more chances of error.

To address this I can think of 2 solutions:
1) Self-Rendered Web Components
2) Extract the HTML fragment & expose the same as REST API

I am more inclined towards the 2nd approach as we already have the working HTML & as I am using CMS, each section of the web is already identified as a component & we have a dedicated template associated with it.
I will need to make this fragment more independent & self-rendered by removing the common dependencies available at the page level.

This way I can expose these sections via Rest endpoints which will return pure HTML output instead of JSON.

I would like to understand to know your opinion & if you see any issues.

Thanks

Comment:   1   2

Comment: Thanks but why do you think I shouldn't go with just Case 2. Are there any drawbacks or any specific benefits going with webcomponents?

Comment: WebComponents encapsulate logic and complexity, makes re-use easier. see https://iconmeister.github.io as example how a WebComponent (aka Custom Element) makes working with SVG easier. Your Solution #2 requires your developers to work with JS code, and they can make all sorts of usage mistakes. So your option isn't 1 **OR** 2. The best is a mix of both (because you already have 2)

Comment: Basically you will wrap a Custom Element (Custom HTML tag) around your API: ``<article-header api="..." query="..."></article-header>``

Answer (score 0):

It's common on MVC framework like .Net Core or Laravel to return a View from a component with all the HTML output, instead of a simple JSON.

So for sure you can do, also from Ajax call